# Call Javascript Function Based on Radio Button Checked Value

Tags: php, javascript

I have a form that sets default values based on a user's account settings (stored in MySQL DB and pulled using PHP). When the form is displayed, it pulls the relevant account information and populates the form (First name, last name, email, account type, etc.)

When a user's account type is 'admin' I want the rest of the form to become disabled, and have certain options selected. If the user's account type is 'admin', and therefore the 'edit_type_admin' radio button checked by default (see below) I would like to call the makeEditDisable() function below as the page is loaded (without requiring any clicks).

Right now the form displays the account type as follows:

```
Client or Admin: <br />
Client <input type="radio" name="edit_type" id="edit_type_client" value="client" <? if($selected_type == 'client') { echo 'checked'; } ?> onclick="makeEditEnable()" />
Admin <input type="radio" name="edit_type" id="edit_type_admin" value="admin" <? if($selected_type == 'admin') { echo 'checked'; } ?> onclick="makeEditDisable()" />
```

When toggling between the two options the onclick makeEditEnable()/makeEditDisable() functions work correctly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function makeEditDisable(){
              var x=document.getElementById("edit_access_begin")
              x.disabled=true;
              var x=document.getElementById("edit_access_expire")
              x.disabled=true;
              var x=document.getElementById("edit_project_access_yes")
              x.checked=true;
              var x=document.getElementById("edit_project_access_yes")
              x.disabled=true;
              var x=document.getElementById("edit_project_access_no")
              x.disabled=true
          }
         function makeEditEnable(){
            var x=document.getElementById("edit_access_begin")
            x.disabled=false;
            var x=document.getElementById("edit_access_expire")
            x.disabled=false;
            var x=document.getElementById("edit_project_access_yes")
            x.disabled=false;
            var x=document.getElementById("edit_project_access_no")
            x.disabled=false
         }</script>
```

Comment: The complete answer to this is a combination of the answers below. I first cleaned up the javascript code as @Vitim.us suggested. I then added `if($selected_type == 'admin') {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload=makeEditDisable;</script>";
    }` sort of as @Jeffman suggested. The only difference is the `window.onload=makeEditDisable` which I  used in order to call the function after the page loaded, which I found here: [http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/javascript-call-funtion-after-page-load/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to a script or function that loads after the elements have loaded, and of course after `makeEditDisable()` has loaded:

```
<? if($selected_type == 'admin') { echo 'makeEditDisable();'; } ?>
```

This should call your function.

Comment: I had to move my PHP variables before the <body> tag on the page so that I could do something like `$body = '<body>';if($selected_type == 'admin') { 
    $body = "<body onLoad='makeEditDisable()'>";
   } `
Thanks!!

Comment: Nope, I lied - nothing needed to move. I just had to add `if($selected_type == 'admin') {
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'>makeEditDisable();</script>";
    }` after the PHP variable $selected_type was declared, and before my form elements that needed to be disabled. Thanks again, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function call to your page using PHP like @Jeffman answer.
But make sure you add this like **after** the script itself or it will generate in `undefined function` error on the client.

or you can call it on the page onload or onDOMReady event.

---

I also want to suggest a cleanup to your script http://jsfiddle.net/DHxvk/

```
var editableFields = ['edit_access_begin','edit_access_expire','edit_project_access_yes','edit_project_access_no'];

function makeEditDisable(){
    for(var i=0; i<editableFields.length; i++)
        document.getElementById(editableFields[i]).disabled=true;
}
function makeEditEnable(){
    for(var i=0; i<editableFields.length; i++)
        document.getElementById(editableFields[i]).disabled=false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for cleaning this up a bit. I know just enough about Javascript to make things functional - but they're not always optimal.